# Spring Whitelabel error page with custom error message

Tags: java, spring

I want to display custom error messages and return status codes.  I am using:

```
@ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.OK,
        reason="No AuthIds available in queue! Push some AuthIds.")
public class NoAuthIdsAvailableException extends RuntimeException {}
```

But when navigating to a page that should throw an error, instead of details on the error I get:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jul 19 16:41:51 EDT 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=OK, status=200).
```